# Fabric.js: How to make the text in a shape to render new line?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to create a textbox on canvas by using fabricJS. I have found a demo on [Fabric official website](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/).

I created a new class for it, and this is my code:

```
 fabric.Writebox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
        type: 'writebox',
        initialize: function(element, options) {
            this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
            options && this.set('lockUniScaling', options.lockUniScaling);
            options && this.set('label', options.label || '');
        },
        toObject: function() {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                label: this.label,
                lockUniScaling: this.lockUniScaling
            });
        },
        _render: function(ctx) {
            this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
            ctx.font = '20px Times';
            ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
            ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width / 2 + 4, -this.height / 2 + 20);
        }
    });
```

and this is how I render/added on my canvas:

```
var theString="Testing the text \n And This is a new line";
$("#textlen").html(theString);
var theWidth = $("#textlen").width();
alert(theWidth);
    var labeledRect = new fabric.Writebox({
        width: 300,
        height: 50,
        left: 300,
        top: 100,
        label: theString,
        fill: '#faa',
        stroke: 1
    });
```

But when the labeledRect is rendered on canvas, the text inside the rect won't display in two lines. Anyone have a solution on this? Thanks!

Comment: can you make jsfiddle of your example? it will be easier to review this

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some code, where text is imputed with '\n'
You can try it